# adding ssl to my react-app to my heroku server

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I am trying to add ssl to my heroku server using certbot.
However, the issue I am finding is that I need to create a url to verify my domain -- which is the issue as I cannot seem to add both my server code as well as my client side code to the same heroku server (and get them to both run at the same time which I need to verify the domain..)

Comment: "I cannot seem to add both my server code as well as my client side code to the same heroku server" - can you clarify that?  Are you using a single domain for this entire application, or are you using a separate API domain for backend?

Comment: Hello, I am using a single domain, and with cerbot I have to add a "get" request to that domain - using express. So yes, the domain is for the whole application

Comment: Got it.  So, I see you are using express.  Can you not just add an express route for that endpoint?

Comment: Yup but the issue is my file structure is: client ->(src,node_modules,package.json) and on the same level as client I have a server.js and package.json and node_modules for the server code. I **cannot** seem to get both to run at the same time without splitting them in a different project. I need them in the same project as to create a route for my domain using certbot http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/abcde. I have tried to create a route using react-router but it just doesn't budge.

Comment: Sorry and when I say "same project" I meant getting them to run in the same terminal rather than having two seperate terminals. I am trying to get "scripts" object in package.json to work as that seems like the only way for me to do it. Any insight would be great

Comment: Gotcha.  I'll post an answer with a suggestion.  If that doesn't work, I would be happy to jump on a SO chat or something

Comment: Also your your scripts, see this blog article: https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-production/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Begin a certbot manual certificate: `sudo certbot certonly --manual`

Follow the prompts until you get to the part that says to make a file available at a specific like like `yourdomain.tld/.well-known/acme-challenge/longstring123`  Do not press Enter to Continue!  Take note of both the URL and the "file" data it gives you.

In your `server.js`, add something like the following:

```
app.get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/your-long-url-string', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200);
  res.send('your-long-verification-file-data');
});
```

Make sure that this Express route handler is above the one you use for React.

Comment: The problem is that yourdomain.tld/.well-known/acme-challenge/longstring123 connects to the react router not the express router. So how do I serve the file from express router if that's the case!

Comment: Hey @AhmedGhrib, this can be easily accomplished by defining the route for the Acme challenge prior to the block that delegates requests to react.  Typically, this will look something like all non-React routes first, then a catch-all route at the end which points to React (handled by react router).  This has been treated on Stack Overflow a number of times, here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334591/how-to-handle-react-router-with-node-express-routing

Comment: Hey, thank you but I fixed it using Express routing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64747255/8965420

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and spent hours trying to figure this out today. My problem was I kept getting a 404 error when trying to access `.well-known/acme-challenge/{verification_file}`.

The problem wasn't React or Heroku, the problem was that I was using `serve -s build` (package serve-handler) to serve my app, this is an static server and it won't let you fetch files without an extension. There might be a way to configure it, but I don't know how. Maybe setting headers... Anyhow, I tried files with `.txt` and it works, but without an extension it redirects to 404.

So instead removed my static server and added ExpressJS to serve the app instead.

To accomplish this:

### Step 1

In your project folder run:

`npm i express path`

### Step 2

Create a file in your project folder called `server.js` and add this code to it. This code will initialize and serve your project.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

### Step 3

If your `package.json` file under scripts make sure Heroku will initialize your project correctly when deployed:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "node server.js",
    ...
 }
```

This should do it. Now your project is served by a dynamic server and it will delivery files without an extension. You can remove your `serve` package now if you aren't going to use it anymore.

### Reading

Couple links that might be useful:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html