# How to handle React Router with Node Express routing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to manage a react app with react router and node js server

my router in react:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute token={token} Component={Payments} exact path="/payments"/>
        <PrivateRoute token={token} Component={User} exact path="/user"/>
        <PrivateRoute token={token} Component={User} exact path=""/>
        <PrivateRoute token={token} Component={User} exact path="/"/>
    </Switch>
<BrowserRouter/>

export const PrivateRoute = ({Component, ...rest,token}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => token ? (<Component {...props}/>) :
            (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>)
        }/>
    )
};
```

and my router in my NodeJS Server :

```
const app = express();
const server = new Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use('/api', router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../react_dist')));
app.use('*',  (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../react_dist', 'index.html'));
});
server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log('Server Is up : ', port)
});
```

when trying to access `localhost:5000/user` react app is working fine
but when I want to access `localhost:5000/api` its redirected to the react app again
cannot figure out how to fix it
what do I need to change?
thanks

Comment: try changing `app.use('*',  (req, res)=> {` to `app.use('/',  (req, res)=> {`

Comment: the problem is inside that switch of react router. you haven't defined the path for /api - which implies if you dont have token and your are trying to access some url it will revert back to react app

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky didnt help :/

Comment: @karthik 
so how to handle route in side react router to node js ?
          <Route path="/api"/>

Comment: Make your port number different for both

Answer (score 14):

You need to define Express routes and controllers to match the front-end request.

This is most likely invalid/not configured properly: `app.use('/api',router);`

Impossible to know for sure unless you paste what your `router` file looks like.

Try replacing it with the matching front-end request:

```
app.delete('/api', callbackfunction)
app.get('/api', callbackfunction)
app.put('/api', callbackfunction)
app.post('/api', callbackfunction)
```

Express needs a request (app.[request]), a route ('/api'), and a controller function (callback function).

```
app.get('/api', (req, res, done) => res.status(201).json({ message: "Hello World!" }));

app.use(express.static('client/build'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve('client', 'build', 'index.html')));

app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 7):

Solved !

because i created the react app with create-react-app cli i needed to add to package.json file this line :

"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

and now when i am trying to make a GET request like that :

axios.get('/api/someurl') is working as expected

thank you all

Comment: i am having similar problem. My backend wirth build front in same directory, is requesting wrong routes. DO you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

What does your express route look like? Like the above user said, it really depends on what your router file looks like on the line

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

There is no need to define your API routes in react-router. However, I think you're misunderstanding how they work together. Usually react-router is used for client side routing while express handles your backend routes such as fetching data. You use react router to route users to different pages and views while your express routes would just render data.

Answer (score 0):

my router :

```
const router = express.Router({});
router.get('/someurl',(res,req)=>{
       res.status(201).json({ message: "Hello World!" })
});
```