# create-react-app | Is it possible to serve a file from backend instead of serving index.html when a browser connect to app

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https, create-react-app, certbot

I have been trying to enable SSL on my MERN heroku-deployed app.
I have been stuck at this step far more than necessary:

---

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@franxyzxyz/setting-up-free-https-with-heroku-ssl-and-lets-encrypt-80cf6eac108e) to set-up SSL certificate on my website.
After, generating the certificate using this command locally:

> sudo certbot certonly --manual

I was asked to do this by the terminal:

> Create a file containing just this data:
>
> dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic.noFTXhkC3HFnZ-RC9djrM6FpWGRy2AFSB17xz59apDA
>
> And make it available on your web server at this URL:
>
> http://www.site_name.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic

According to the tutorial, I had to do this on the backend:

```
app.get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:content', function(req, res) {
  res.send('xxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyy.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz')
})
```

I did that, and as expected it did not work since the certbot will be targeting the front-end and not the backend according to this:

> Create a file containing just this data:
>
> dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic.noFTXhkC3HFnZ-RC9djrM6FpWGRy2AFSB17xz59apDA
>
> And make it available on your web server at this URL:
>
> http://www.site_name.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic

And it just doesn't make sense for me, to make this data available

> dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic.noFTXhkC3HFnZ-RC9djrM6FpWGRy2AFSB17xz59apDA

on the client side.
**So my question is:** Should it be available on the client side or the server side? It it's on the server side, should I just write code on the client side that would communicate with the server in order to retrieve it?

---

So when the verification process happens and it tries to access the backend endpoint through this:

```
http://www.site_name.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dC9Ry5Ps_qgkOheuWnxCXFobim8vshqMqbDC9FQS4ic
```

The app treats it as it's trying to access client-side file...
In other words, **I am unable to make it target the backend endpoint**.
All tutorials are ignoring this point and it makes me feel like I'm missing something or that I'm stupid.

So any idea what I should do?

---

This [guy](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6713) seems to be having the same problem as me but no answer was provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for my own MERN Stack application and it works, furthermore I always deploy my projects on heroku.

**First thing that I do I first generate my SSL Cert and Key using:--> openssl**

- This is the command you would want to run: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`
- This command will generate you two files `cert.perm` and `key.pem`

**Now it time to setup your server's https**

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

//GET home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

// we will pass our 'app' to 'https' server
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),

}, app).listen(3000);
```

- Noting the with convention you can also have an `http` server hooked up by doing the same as `http.createServer` and all you do is pass down the `express app`.
- However if the are certain things that you want to restrict for `http` then you can separate the two from not using the same **express app** I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Serving a static file from backend.

1. Create a file in the root folder (root_folder/sec/ssl) containing the code :
   [image]

2. Add this to your express router:

---

```
// Server static assets if in production
// Check if we are in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  // We want to get anything that is not one of those api routes
  /********************************** */
  /***Adding the certbot verification code */
  /********************************** */
  app.get(
    "/.well-known/acme-challenge/url_code",
    (req, res) => {
      console.log(
        "get(/.well-known/acme-challenge/ur_code)"
      );
      // __dirname is the current directory name
      //We will tell the server if none of those routes are being hit then look into the build folder index.html
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "sec", "ssl"));
    }
  );
  /*********************************** */
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    // __dirname is the current directory name
    //We will tell the server if none of those routes are being hit then look into the build folder index.html
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

That's it!